# write.csv, file extension .csv in Rstudio not working

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to write a csv for my analysis results. Somehow when I use the .csv extenions it does not work. However when I erase the .csv after the file title it makes a general file. I do not understand where the problem is, could anyone help me with that?
This is the code:

```
write.csv(BLUES_overview, "Parameters_Fv_Fm_def.csv")
```

This is the error I get:

> Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :    cannot open the
> connection In addition: Warning message: In file(file, ifelse(append,
> "a", "w")) :   cannot open file 'Parameters_Fv_Fm_def.csv': Permission
> denied

Comment: Have you created a file called `Parameters_Fv_Fm_def.csv`? Or is it open when you run the code? If it's close it and try running the code again.

Comment: @VishalA. No, I did not open it.  I even tried giving it different names when creating it but it did not help.

Comment: `getwd()` will confirm the working directory where the file should be being written - is this a directory that you have write access? Does changing the filename solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The error stems from not having write permissions in your working directory:

```
> setwd("/root")
> write.csv(cars, "cars.csv")
Error in file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) : 
  cannot open the connection
In addition: Warning message:
In file(file, ifelse(append, "a", "w")) :
  cannot open file 'cars.csv': Permission denied
>
```

You can get your current working directory with `getwd()` and set it with `setwd("/path/to/your/working/directory")`.